# RelativeLayout scrolling with two listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/campomodulo"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="21sp"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listagiocatori"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/campomodulo" >

     </ListView>

     <ListView
     android:id="@+id/panchina"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/listagiocatori" >

</ListView>
```

The first listview fills about half display, adding the second just below that, the total height of the two listviews exceeds the screen, so i have a scroll on the second listview.

I would like a general scrolling, not only for the second listview. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique ScrollView and then create two different linearlayouts to "implement" your listview. Then you add your items programmatically like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyListLayout);
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
Item item = list.get(i);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyRowLayout, null);
Textview myTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.MyTextView);
myTextView.setText(item.getString());
list.addView(vi);
```

The main layout should look similar to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/campomodulo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="21sp"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/campomodulo">

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/listagiocatori"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/panchina"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/listagiocatori" >
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then you just need to set a simple layout for every row in order to add it to the appropriate layouts. It can be simply a TextView or a more elaborated layout